# Error when starting pm2 getting module_conf.json not existing

Tags: node.js, pm2

When I start pm2, I get this

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\.pm2\module_conf.json'
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

1 . Add user environment variable as below:

```
PM2_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\.pm2
```

2 . Restart command line

```
cmd
```

3 . Then kill pm2 daemon once

```
pm2 kill
```

4 . Now run pm2 as usual (An example is below)

```
pm2 start ./bin/www
```